# Grub menu on reboot after removing another distro partition

Tags: ubuntu, osx, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I just acquired a macbook air. I dual-booted mac os with Ubuntu. It is my first time multiple-booting on a mac. I triple-booted with another Ubuntu. Ater removing the third distro, I experience some issues with grub.

First of all, I made my partitions as follow:

```
$ lsblk
sda
  sda1  200M    /boot/efi
  sda2  47.3GB              # Mac os
  sda3  620MB               # Mac rescue
  sda4  2GB                 # Swap partition
  sda5  50GB                # Ubuntu 1
  sda6  50GB                # Ubuntu 2
  sda10 100GB               # ext4 file system
```

I did an install of Ubuntu on `sda5`. Once finished, it directly boots with Ubuntu which is great. I later installed another ubuntu on `sda6` as I would like to test using other ditros and I want to check if I could do that easily. Note that the Ubuntu version is the exact same I installed on another partition. Once the second Ubuntu installed, I reboot and I have the grub screen asking me to chose between the two Ubuntus. Neat. Then, having no use for the second ubuntu, I simply erased `sda6` using `gdisk`:

```
$ gdisk /dev/sda
> d  # delete partition
> 6  # delete partition 6
> w  # write changes
> Y  # confirmation of writing changes.
> q  # quit gdisk

$ lsblk
sda
  sda1  200M    /boot/efi
  sda2  47.3GB              # Mac os
  sda3  620MB               # Mac rescue
  sda4  2GB                 # Swap partition
  sda5  50GB                # Ubuntu 1
  sda10 100GB               # ext4 file system
```

Now on reboot, I get the grub command line on black screen. I have to specify the disk where my ubuntu is located. I followed some indications in this thread to boot on Ubuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead  and tried doing the following:

```
grub> ls (hd2,gpt5)  # That's my Ubuntu partition
grub> root=(hd2,gpt5)
grub> configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Now I succesfully booted in Ubuntu. After logging in, I followed the instrutions on updating grub:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Alas when rebooting, the grub screen pops up again. So updating grub did not do the trick. I also tried to do with grub 2 in case:

```
$ sudo update-grub2
```

It does not change anything.

I also tried to reinstall the second version of Ubuntu on sda6. Same scheme, when I reboot, I am asked to chose between the two Ubuntu versions in the grub menu, so it kind of solves the issue. But as soon as I remove the second Ubuntu partition, the first one won't boot directly unless I specify it in the grub command line screen.

I don't know if this might be useful, but here is my fstab:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=85ab4560-729a-4f7d-91d9-69af89ea1219 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=DAC6-DEC2  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=9c76739a-5996-43d8-a14e-fe690c06870f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What can I do to solve this issue? Is it a matter of EFI? Why removing the second Ubuntu partition makes the first one unrecognized to grub?

Note that I would like to find a clean solution, so I would like to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by getting hints from this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi

I did not need to use a live installation, I just booted into my ubuntu session through the grub window. I then reinstalled grub:

$ apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64

This also did an update-grub automatically. It works and updated the grub.cfg file in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, updating the right partition to boot ubuntu from:

```
$ cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
search.fs_uuid 17441147-6b9d-45fe-bccd-bed2451f43f8 root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Previously, running

$ update-grub

would not update neither the uuid nor the partition, old partition was the latest ubuntu's, named hd0,gpt6. So it seems reinstalling grub was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  recreate the `grub.cfg` using the following command:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Or

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for your answer. Once booted on my ubuntu, I recreated the `grub.cfg`: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then I updated `grub`: `sudo update-grub`. I rebooted but the `grub` black screen is displayed again. DId I miss something?

Comment: Sould I also do a `grub install` on the hard drive?

Comment: Yes you should install grub on the hdd

Comment: Wouldn't that mess with the MAC bootloader or anything?

Comment: First partition is  an EFI System Partition. Then two mac partitions, 1 linux swap, two linux filesystem with one for ubuntu. What would running a `grub install` on the whole disk do?