# Laptop boots to grub menu after uninstalling one of 2 dual booted linux distrobutions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, grub

I installed two Ubuntu based linux distributions on my acer laptop. I eventually decided I liked one of the two better and deleted the other distributions partition, but now when I boot the computer it boots to the grub command line. I am able to boot into my still installed linux distribution by using the commands `set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub` and `set root=hd0,gpt2` by default they are both set to gpt1. I want to install a user friendly distro of linux on this computer because im giving it to a family member and i've already gotten all the important files off so I thought id just reinstall everything, but ive been unable to even boot off of a USB stick it stills just goes to grub menu.

Ive looked through this thread [Grub menu on reboot after removing another distro partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289272/grub-menu-on-reboot-after-removing-another-distro-partition) as it seems they had a similar issue and tried reinstalling grub and using the solution in the thread, `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64` and nothing has fixed it.

I dont care about any of the data on this laptop as i'm just looking to put a clean install of some other linux distro on it.

Comment: I see two possible reasons why your laptop doesn't boot from USB:
(a) The USB stick is somehow corrupted and not bootable (wrong image writing tool/method used or corrupted ISO) or (b) your BIOS boot order is wrong or set to a boot method (UEFI/legacy) not supported by the Linux image. Check that USB has the highest boot priority in BIOS, set UEFI/legacy boot mode to "both" and secure boot to "off". You can also try a different USB port or different USB stick. Your current grub installation is not the reason.

Comment: @Freddy seems like the usb wasn't working which is weird because it worked on another computer. Thanks seems like I just need to flash the usb stick again.

Comment: I have seen laptops that wouldn't boot from USB sticks that worked fine everywhere else. Copying that image to a different stick (same vendor, different model) worked for unknown reasons. Strange, but it happens... ;) Please write a [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) when you solved the issue, you can accept your answer after two days. Thank you!